# Invocablemethod Not Creating Records in Apex Class

Tags: salesforce, apex, salesforce-development, salesforce-developer

I'm pretty new to writing Apex but everything does seem to be running smoothly separately in an executable window when I split apart the class I created below, but when I'm running this from within a flow it doesn't seem to create the records at all. The methods that delete records seem to be working, but neither of the methods to create the records is working it seems.

Any help or guidance is much appreciated!

```
public without sharing class CreateQuoteProducts_NewOrRenewal{
    @invocableMethod
    public static void DeleteQuoteProductsMRF(List<Id> OrderId){
        List<Quote_Product_MRF__c> QuoteProductsMRF = [SELECT id from Quote_Product_MRF__c WHERE Order__c in : OrderId];
        if(!QuoteProductsMRF.isEmpty()){
            delete QuoteProductsMRF;
        }
    }
    public static void DeleteQuoteProductsOTF(List<Id> OrderId){
        List<Quote_Product__c> QuoteProductsOTF = [SELECT id from Quote_Product__c WHERE Order__c in : OrderId];
        if(!QuoteProductsOTF.isEmpty()){
            delete QuoteProductsOTF;
        }
    }

/* ---START--- Create Quote Products MRF ---START--- */

    public static void CreateQuoteProductsMRF(List<Id> OrderId){
        List<AggregateResult> nrqpmrfOP = [
        SELECT 

        count(Id) ct,
        Order__c ord,
        sum(Total_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c) stmr,
        sum(Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c) mr,
        sum(Discount_MRF__c) dmr

        FROM Order_Location_Package__c 
        WHERE Order__c in : OrderId AND Package__r.Monthly_Recurring_Price__c != null
        GROUP BY Package__c, Order__c];


        List<Quote_Product_MRF__c> nrqpmrf = New List<Quote_Product_MRF__c>();
        for(AggregateResult ar : nrqpmrfOP){


        Quote_Product_MRF__c QuoteProductMRF = New Quote_Product_MRF__c();
        QuoteProductMRF.Quantity__c = (Decimal)ar.get('ct');
        QuoteProductMRF.Order__c = (String)ar.get('ord');
        QuoteProductMRF.Total_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c = (Decimal)ar.get('stmr');
        QuoteProductMRF.Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c = (Decimal)ar.get('mr');
        QuoteProductMRF.Discount_MRF__c = (Decimal)ar.get('dmr');
        QuoteProductMRF.Product_Type__c = 'Package';

        nrqpmrf.add(QuoteProductMRF);
        } 

        Insert nrqpmrf;
    }
/* ---END--- Create Quote Products MRF ---END--- */

/* ---START--- Create Quote Products OTF ---START--- */

    public static void CreateQuoteProductsOTF(List<Id> OrderId){
        List<AggregateResult> nrqpmrfOP = [
        SELECT 

        count(Id) ct,
        Order__c ord,
        sum(Total_One_Time_Fees__c) stmr,
        sum(One_Time_Fees__c) mr,
        sum(Discount_OTF__c) dmr

        FROM Order_Location_Package__c 
        WHERE Order__c in : OrderId AND Package__r.One_Time_Price__c != null
        GROUP BY Package__c, Order__c];


        List<Quote_Product__c> nrqpotf = New List<Quote_Product__c>();
        for(AggregateResult ar : nrqpmrfOP){


        Quote_Product__c QuoteProductOTF = New Quote_Product__c();
        QuoteProductOTF.Quantity__c = (Decimal)ar.get('ct');
        QuoteProductOTF.Order__c = (String)ar.get('ord');
        QuoteProductOTF.Total_One_Time_Fees__c = (Decimal)ar.get('stmr');
        QuoteProductOTF.One_Time_Fees__c = (Decimal)ar.get('mr');
        QuoteProductOTF.Discount_OTF__c = (Decimal)ar.get('dmr');
        QuoteProductOTF.Product_Type__c = 'Package';

        nrqpotf.add(QuoteProductOTF);
        } 

        Insert nrqpotf;
    }
/* ---END--- Create Quote Products ORD ---END--- */

}
```

Test Class Below

```
@isTest
private class CreateQuoteProducts_NewOrRenewalTest {

    private static testMethod void doTest() {
        
        Account testAcc  = new Account ();          
                testAcc.Name = 'Test Account';
                testAcc.Primary_Vertical__c = 'Multifamily Housing';
                testAcc.Total_Locations_Owned_Managed__c = 1;
                
                insert testAcc;


        Opportunity testOpp  = new Opportunity ();
                testOpp.Name = 'Test Opportunity';
                testOpp.AccountId = testAcc.Id;
                testOpp.Opportunity_Source__c = 'Sales Generated';
                testOpp.Type = 'New';
                testOpp.StageName = 'Contract';
                testOpp.Number_of_locations_for_opportunity__c = 1;
                testOpp.Amount = 0;
                testOpp.Implementation__c = 0;
                testOpp.CloseDate = System.today() + 5;
                testOpp.Deal_Confidence__c = 100;
                
                insert testOpp;

        Package__c testPackage  = new Package__c ();
                testPackage.Name = 'Test Package';
                testPackage.Package_Type__c = 'Website Package';
                testPackage.Status__c = 'Active';
                testPackage.One_Time_Price__c = String.ValueOf(200);
                testPackage.Monthly_Recurring_Price__c = String.ValueOf(100);
                
                insert testPackage;


        Order_Sheet__c testOrder  = new Order_Sheet__c ();
                testOrder.Opportunity__c = testOpp.id;
                
                insert testOrder;


        Order_New_Location__c testOrderLocation  = new Order_New_Location__c ();
                testOrderLocation.Order_Sheet__c = testOrder.id;
                testOrderLocation.Name = 'Test Location';
                
                insert testOrderLocation;


        Order_Location_Package__c testOrderPackage  = new Order_Location_Package__c ();
                testOrderPackage.Order__c = testOrder.Id;
                testOrderPackage.New_Location_Name__c = testOrderLocation.Id;
                testOrderPackage.Package__c = testPackage.Id;
                
                insert testOrderPackage;


/* --- Delete Quote Product MRF Test --- */

        Test.startTest();
        /* --- Create Quote Product MRF--- */
        Quote_Product_MRF__c testQPMRF  = new Quote_Product_MRF__c ();
                testQPMRF.Order__c = testOrder.id;
                
                insert testQPMRF;

        /* --- Run Delete Method--- */
        CreateQuoteProducts_NewOrRenewal.DeleteQuoteProductsMRF(new List<Id>{testOrder.id});
        
        /* --- Query for QP OTF--- */
        list<Quote_Product_MRF__c>queriedQPMRF = [Select Id FROM Quote_Product_MRF__c WHERE Order__c = :testOrder.id];
        
        /* --- Checks for 0 records --- */
        system.assertEquals(0, queriedQPMRF.size());



/* --- Delete Quote Product OTF Test --- */

        /* --- Create Quote Product OTF--- */
        Quote_Product__c testQPOTF  = new Quote_Product__c ();
                testQPOTF.Order__c = testOrder.id;
                
                insert testQPOTF;

        /* --- Run Delete Method--- */
        CreateQuoteProducts_NewOrRenewal.DeleteQuoteProductsOTF(new List<Id>{testOrder.id});
        
        /* --- Query for QP OTF--- */
        list<Quote_Product__c>queriedQPOTF = [Select Id FROM Quote_Product__c WHERE Order__c = :testOrder.id];
        
        /* --- Checks for 0 records --- */
        system.assertEquals(0, queriedQPOTF.size());


 /* --- Create Quote Product MRF Test --- */


        /* --- Run Create Method--- */
        CreateQuoteProducts_NewOrRenewal.CreateQuoteProductsMRF(new List<Id>{testOrder.id});
        
        /* --- Query for QP OTF--- */
        list<Quote_Product_MRF__c>queriedQPMRFCreated = [Select Id FROM Quote_Product_MRF__c WHERE Order__c = :testOrder.id];
        
        /* --- Checks for 1 record --- */
        system.assertEquals(1, queriedQPMRFCreated.size());



 /* --- Create Quote Product OTF Test --- */


        /* --- Run Create Method--- */
        CreateQuoteProducts_NewOrRenewal.CreateQuoteProductsOTF(new List<Id>{testOrder.id});
        
        /* --- Query for QP OTF--- */
        list<Quote_Product__c>queriedQPOTFCreated = [Select Id FROM Quote_Product__c WHERE Order__c = :testOrder.id];
        
        /* --- Checks for 1 record --- */
        system.assertEquals(1, queriedQPOTFCreated.size());

        Test.stopTest();


    }
}
```

As mentioned above, if I run the below apex in an executable window and replace the ID with and actual Order Id, it does successfully create the records, just not when I run the full class from flow.

```
    List<AggregateResult> nrqpmrfOP = [
    SELECT 

    count(Id) ct,
    Order__c ord,
    sum(Total_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c) stmr,
    sum(Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c) mr,
    sum(Discount_MRF__c) dmr

    FROM Order_Location_Package__c 
    WHERE Order__c in : OrderId AND Package__r.Monthly_Recurring_Price__c != null
    GROUP BY Package__c, Order__c];


    List<Quote_Product_MRF__c> nrqpmrf = New List<Quote_Product_MRF__c>();
    for(AggregateResult ar : nrqpmrfOP){


    Quote_Product_MRF__c QuoteProductMRF = New Quote_Product_MRF__c();
    QuoteProductMRF.Quantity__c = (Decimal)ar.get('ct');
    QuoteProductMRF.Order__c = (String)ar.get('ord');
    QuoteProductMRF.Total_Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c = (Decimal)ar.get('stmr');
    QuoteProductMRF.Monthly_Recurring_Fees__c = (Decimal)ar.get('mr');
    QuoteProductMRF.Discount_MRF__c = (Decimal)ar.get('dmr');
    QuoteProductMRF.Product_Type__c = 'Package';

    nrqpmrf.add(QuoteProductMRF);
    } 

    Insert nrqpmrf;
```

Comment: Could you tell us what is the sharing setting of `Order_Location_Package__c ` ? You should specify wether your class run in `with sharing` or `without sharing` to also avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks, Bartheleway! I made the update above - it should be ```without sharing```

Comment: As specified in documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm), there can be only 1 InvocableMethod by class. This means that your flow only call the first delete method, not the others. If you need to call each method, then you need to do a class for each. Maybe a screenshot of the flow might help.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, thanks for pointing that out. I'll split these up into different classes. Appreciate your help Bartheleway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As specified in documentation (developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/…), there can be only 1 InvocableMethod by class. This means that your flow only call the first delete method, not the others. If you need to call each method, then you need to do a class for each. Maybe a screenshot of the flow might help. – Bartheleway